# Filter text file, with matlab or other program

Tags: matlab

I have this huge file with wind data from 1953 to 2010, wind speed and wind direction is recorded every hour as shown below. I was wondering if it was possible to filter this file so it only contains wind speeds say above 12 m/s for example. So the dataset would be decreased dramatically. Is this possible to do with Matlab or any other program? What is the simplest way to do it?

```
    Year, month, day, hour, wind speed, wind direction, wind direction
    1953    1   1   0   10.0    90  90
    1953    1   1   1   10.0    90  90
    1953    1   1   2   10.0    90  90
    1953    1   1   3   8.0     90  90
    1953    1   1   4   8.0     90  90
    1953    1   1   5   13.0    90  90
    1953    1   1   6   13.0    70  70
    1953    1   1   7   14.0    90  90
    1953    1   1   8   16.0    90  90
    1953    1   1   9   13.0    90  90
    1953    1   1   10  13.0    90  90
    1953    1   1   11  16.0    90  90
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove comma (,) from header and save file then use code below

```
#Read file space deliminator, Offset row=1, col=0
filename = 'input.txt';
M = dlmread(filename,' ',1,0)
#Find index of Speed that is M(:,5) > 12.0
Idx = find(M(:, 5)> 12.0)
#Extact all columns of index (or rows)
M = M(Idx, :)
```